# Recurrence complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, recurrence

Find the tight asymptotic bound:

> T(n) =      1 if n = 1
>
> 2T(n/4) + T(n/2) + n<sup>2</sup> if n > 1

I tried drawing a recurrence tree. First row I had n<sup>2</sup>, second row I had (3/8)(n<sup>4</sup>), third row I had (27/1024)(n<sup>8</sup>).. Don't know how to continue from there.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) can be applied in this problem. It is much easier to understand than recurrence tree.

Write the recurrence formula in another form. Add `T(n/2)` to both the left and right side.

> T(n) + T(n/2) = + 2T(n/4) + 2T(n/2)  + n<sup>2</sup>
>
> T(n) + T(n/2) = + 2[ T(n/4) + T(n/2) ]  + n<sup>2</sup>

Define `G(n) = T(n) + T(n/2)`, then

> G(1) = Θ(1)
>
> G(n) = 2G(n/2) + n<sup>2</sup>, if n > 1

Apply the Master Theorem to the above new recurrence formula

> G(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

that is

> T(n) + T(n/2) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

for n > 1

> T(n) = 2 * T(n/4) + T(n/2) + n<sup>2</sup>
>
> = T(n/4) + [ T(n/2) + T(n/4) ] + n<sup>2</sup>
>
> = T(n/4) + Θ(n2/4) + n2
>
> = T(n/4) + Θ(n2)

Apply the Master Theorem to the above new recurrence formula

> T(n) = Θ(n2)

Comment: Interesting way of thinking. However, here:  G(n) = 2G(n/2) + n2  If you open 2G(n/2) you should get 2T(n/2) + 2T(n/4), which does not equal the original: 2T(n/2) + T(n/4).

Comment: @amitooshacham You should also open the left part of `G(n) = 2G(n/2) + n^2`, and get `T(n) + T(n/2) = 2T(n/2) + 2T(n/4) + n^2`, that is `T(n) = T(n/2) + 2T(n/4) + n^2`